# SQL Server: How to open a URL using Job script on a timely basis?

Tags: sql-server, job-scheduling, sql-agent-job

I want to open a URL using SQL Server Job Script in Asynchronous way. Currently I am able to make the call to the target. However for some reason SQL Server Job remains active and 'In Progress'. Don't know how to stop it automatically after running it once. Kindly help me out guys.

Following are the details of my Job Script:

"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://testing.com/call-page/"

type: operating system

run as: server agent service

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check Security Event Log for an Audit Failure event.

You may need to create a Proxy Account but the Credentials used may still be denied based on Group Policy.

Is there a need to use SQL Server Agent?  Can you use Task Scheduler?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Its actually quite simply done. I have created a Job script and in its one & only step, I have added the above line. Which actually works. The only problem is that, that particular step remains in 'In Progress' mode and I have to manually stop the Job from SSMS Job Agent. I just want the step to hit the target URL and finishes of in an asynchronous way, i.e. demanding no output.